# where is php phalcon's config?

Tags: php, phalcon

I installed phalcon follow it's [Compilation document](https://phalconphp.com/en/download) , the command showed that I install and build succeed. But when I run config script `<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>` it reported error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/php55-phalcon/phalcon.so' - dlopen(@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/php55-phalcon/phalcon.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/php55-phalcon/phalcon.so' - dlopen(@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/php55-phalcon/phalcon.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

`locate` shows that there are two phalcon.so, the first was installed by phalcon's `install` sctipt, the second was installed by  `brew install php5x php5x-phalcon`

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.27_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/phalcon.so
/usr/local/Cellar/php55-phalcon/2.0.6/phalcon.so
```

I don't know where is the phalcon's config, maybe it found phalcon.so from the wrong place.

How to fix it?

edit:

I found the phalcon's config file and change the path of phalcon.so, and the error still there.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55-phalcon/2.1.6/phalcon.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55-phalcon/2.1.6/phalcon.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55-phalcon/2.1.6/phalcon.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55-phalcon/2.1.6/phalcon.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: You sure it's not just a typo? The error message you have there mentions a Phalcon version 2.1.6, but the current one is 2.0.6. Like the one that brew installed for you. Check the difference in those library paths.